# How to screen a cable

Tags: emc, cables

I have a small cheap cable, four discrete wires (5V, GND, CLK, D) with a simple white connector on each side. I get EMI on this cable - not a lot, but enough to disrupt the operation. What's the best way to add a screen to this cable? I would expect something like a shrink tube with braids, but can't find it. Other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Shrink tube with internal EMI braid exists; I think Glenair and TE both sell it but the cost is prohibitive. Is replacing the cheap cable with something shielded that's a little bit more expensive out of the question?

Comment: Everything counts, especially if i can do it quickly.

Comment: If you search for "interference shielding wrap around sleeving" you'll find some stuff that might work (for "only" $6-10 per foot), especially if the cable is permanently terminated into connectors on each end. I'm not sure how if or how you intend to ground it though.

Comment: i would ground by simply connecting to the GND wire on each side

Comment: How long is the cable and what is the source of the EMI? It could just be crosstalk in the cable.

Comment: What do you mean by "get EMI" -- emissions, or susceptibility to nearby emissions? What is CLK/D, digital I assume, what signal level and data rate? Edge rate? Drive strength?

Comment: Is it an option to just replace the cable with a shielded one, and ground the shield?  There are plenty of 4+-core shielded cables out there.  Alternatively, I have had reasonable luck just wrapping cables with aluminium tape (it won't stand much mechanical abuse though).

Comment: What goes in the cable? How long? How big connectors? How quickly you need to do this, and is this a one-off thing for an emergency, or do you need to handle this professionally with cheap manufacturability for millions of products? Sometimes, screening the cable, or changing the cable to screened, will be more expensive than designing the devices that the cable connects propery to begin with.

Comment: So the cable is about 15cm long. It catches interference from nearby switching node of a motor drive. The interference is is stronger when the cable is closer to the motor phase wire. The connectors are small, T1M. The solution I am looking for should be a quick fix, later I'll figure out what to do in production. I have ordered a shielded cable to simply solder it to the connector. Hope it will work, but obviously it can't be like that in production

Comment: Motors make life hard sometimes.  Shielding the motor circuitry instead of the cable might be another option, though probably not cheap or easy. Something like a copper cover to block electric fields, or a ferromagnetic cover to block magnetic fields.  Or both.  A shielded cable seems simpler if it works but probably wouldn't be very effective if the interference is predominantly magnetic.

Comment: Yeah... the motor part is so large that i can't cover it now. Later it will altogether enclosed. This cable is for the current sensor, sort of belongs :)

Comment: If you have a need to transfer a clock signal to a motor sensor, then the problem is that the sensor is horribly designed. Shielding the cable will not solve that, it's like cleaning the floor by hiding the dirt underneath the carpet. Switch to a sensor suitable for industrial applications.

Comment: @Lundin or I am designing something different from what's available. It's a 2000A high resolution sensor

Answer (score 1):

OK, the quick and dirty way was to order a shielded cable on Amazon and solder it to the T1M connectors. This is how it looks:[image]

The EMI is gone for now. An open question is what to do for production. If there would be something like RJ45, but miniature, would be really cool. I'll search for it. I appreciate all the comments and help.